# using fsolve with string equations

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I'm trying to solve an equation with fsolve, however my equation is a string. I tried using eval but that did not work. Is there a way to pass a string/convert the string into something fsolve can handle? Below is my code:

```
def sub(x):
    eqn1 = "4x + 3y = 20"
    eqn2 = "-5x + 9y = 26"
    y = "({})".format(converter(eqn1))
    return eval(eqn2.replace("y", y).replace("=", "-").replace("x", "*x").replace("((", "*(("))
print(fsolve(sub, 0))
```

Comment: The approach will be awkward. `fsolve` calls this function many times, so it should be an eficient, well written one, not something cobbled tkgether from strings each time it

Comment: I'd sugest first learn to use `fsolve` with a normal function.  Then look into creating a matching function from strings.  `sympy` might help.  Either use its own solver, or use `sympy.lambdify` to make a numpy function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve equations formatted strings, [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html), Python's library for symbolic math could be used. It has a function [`parse_expr`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html) which can cope a.o. with a missing multiplication operator.

```py
from sympy import solve, Eq
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import standard_transformations, implicit_multiplication_application

eqn1 = "4x + 3y = 20"
eqn2 = "-5x + 9y = 26"
transformations = (standard_transformations + (implicit_multiplication_application,))

sides1 = [parse_expr(s, transformations=transformations) for s in eqn1.split('=')]
sides2 = [parse_expr(s, transformations=transformations) for s in eqn2.split('=')]
sol = solve([Eq(sides1[0], sides1[1]),
             Eq(sides2[0], sides2[1])])
print(sol)
```

Result: `{x: 2, y: 4}`

To solve the equations separately, with `y` a function of `x`, [`lambdify()`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) can convert the solution to a numpy function. Here is some example code converting each equation to a function and afterwards plotting them.

```py
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve, lambdify
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import standard_transformations, implicit_multiplication_application

x, y = symbols("x y")
eqn1 = "4x + 3y = 20"
eqn2 = "-5x + 9y = 26"
equations = [eqn1, eqn2]
transformations = (standard_transformations + (implicit_multiplication_application,))
solutions = []
solutions_np = []
for eqn in equations:
    sides = [parse_expr(s, transformations=transformations, local_dict={'x': x, 'y': y})
             for s in eqn.split('=')]
    sol = solve([Eq(sides[0], sides[1])], y)
    solutions.append(sol[y])
    solutions_np.append(lambdify(x, sol[y]))

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = np.linspace(-5, 10)
for eqn, sol, sol_np in zip(equations, solutions, solutions_np):
    plt.plot(xs, sol_np(xs), label=f'${eqn}$;  $y = {sol}$')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: This would solve the system not the combined equation, would this same method work with a single equation?